# How to export React component as npm package? Create-React-App SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, create-react-app

I have created react app which name is "create-react-app-npm". And in the ./src/index.js file I have exported  component to use it npm package in the another project. Firstly I have run this code in my main root.

`npm run eject` and then next part of my project

#### This is the src/index.js in the create-react-app-npm folder

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

class ExportApp extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(<App sayHi="hello There I am creating my first npm package"/>);
    }
}
export default ExportApp;
```

#### this is the package.json file in the create-react-app-npm folder

```
{
  "name": "create-react-app-npm",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.5.5",
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "1.13.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.3",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.0.1",
    "camelcase": "^5.2.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "dotenv": "6.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "3.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.14.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "is-wsl": "^1.1.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "0.1.0",
    "jest-resolve": "24.8.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.3.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.5.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.5.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "7.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.2",
    "react-dev-utils": "^9.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "resolve": "1.12.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "7.2.0",
    "semver": "6.3.0",
    "style-loader": "1.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.4.1",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.2",
    "url-loader": "2.1.0",
    "webpack": "4.39.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.2.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

I have run `npm link` in the terminal while I am in the root folder of my project.

After I have created this main project, I have also created `npm_test` project folder by using `create-react-app npm_test` code.

I have run `npm link create-react-app-npm` code to link previous `main project which is create-react-app-npm` and my second npm-test project.

My App.js file as follows in my `npm-test` project folder.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ExportApp from 'create-react-app-npm'

function App2() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <ExportApp/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App2;
```

when I run npm start I could not run the project. I have got the error messages. I do not have any ideas what does it mean. What should I do?

### Error is like this

```
Failed to compile.

../create-react-app-npm/src/index.js
SyntaxError: /home/semih/Desktop/create-react-app-npm/src/index.js: Unexpected token (7:15)

   5 | class ExportApp extends React.Component{
   6 |     render(){
>  7 |         return(<App sayHi="hello There I am creating my first npm package"/>);
     |                ^
   8 |     }
   9 | }
  10 | export default ExportApp;
```

I have expected to run `ExportMain` component in the `npm-test` project. What should be the path which I should follow?

Comment: The error means, your JSX has not been transpiled into valid JavaScript syntax. CRA in your main project does not transpile JSX from node_modules (component lib). Build your library for node - e.g. config from [here](https://medium.com/code-oil/webpack-javascript-bundling-for-both-front-end-and-back-end-b95f1b429810), adjust your main field in package.json to be the dist index.js and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However my webpack-config file is different from any examples on the internet. I do not know how to configure it according to website which you have given above. My webpack-config file code sample is as follows;

```const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
      isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('style-loader'),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        options: shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths ? { publicPath: '../../' } : {},
      },```

Comment: (https://github.com/SemihOzden/npm_example) this is the my create-react-app-npm repository link. I want to create npm package with it in local and then import another react project in my local computer. What should I do with it?

Answer (score 5):

Create React App/CRA is not the optimal tool to build and bundle npm packages, its [main purpose](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started) is to create Single Page Applications. For component libraries, CRA team [recommends](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#recommended-toolchains) to use [more flexible toolchains](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#more-flexible-toolchains).

As you have ejected CRA, you can still try to adjust Webpack config. Here is an example config with the essential settings targeting npm packages:

```
// simply way to exclude all node_modules from bundle.
// You can configure entries manually, too.
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  ...
  output: {
    // provide entry point exports via CommonJS / as npm package
    libraryTarget: "commonjs"
  },
  ...
  // ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
  target: "node",
  // don't bundle node_modules with your library
  // external packages should be required
  externals: [nodeExternals()]
};
```

Concerning CRA, add those settings to the base config `<root>/config/webpack.config.js`. Possible Further adjustments:

```
output: {
  // give your main npm package file a static name
  // It should be stored to build/node_bundle.js
  filename: "node_bundle.js"
},
```

package.json:

```
"main": "build/node_bundle.js"
```

Last, build your library and require it in your client application.

#### Links:

- Webpack [libraryTarget](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget) setting
- Webpack [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) setting
- [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals)
- [Authoring libraries](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/)

Comment: Very useful answer. I've been using CRA to create it for a long time, it bothered me for a few days. Consider packaging with rollup later. Thank you!

Comment: Does it create a separate CSS file? How to get this CSS linked to this JS bundle and accept tree shaking on production build when the library user importing component from this?