# Using create-react-app project as a npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new on reactjs.

**I developed a project and I would like use my common project on my new project as a npm package.**

Now,

I could install package from git repo but when I import css files in any component, its ok, it works but when I want import and use a component from my common project it doesn't transpiled from react-script I guess...

Do I have to use webpack ? (because I don't want use it)
How can i fix my error without webpack?
If webpack is must what can I provide for?

```
My New Project package.json:
{
  "name": "react-sample",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "acshb-react-common": "git+https://<my-username>:<my-token>@github.com/<my-username>/<my-repo>.git#master"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

My Common Project package.json:
{
  "name": "<my-common-project-nam>",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": false,
  "author": "<my-name>",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "<common-project-repo-url>"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "echarts": "^4.2.1",
    "echarts-for-react": "^2.0.15-beta.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^3.1.8",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-overlay": "^2.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.0.8",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit": "^2.0.1",
    "react-cookie": "^4.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-number-format": "^4.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^5.3.2",
    "react-toggle-button": "^2.2.0",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.10.0",
    "react-widgets": "^4.4.11",
    "react-widgets-moment": "^4.0.27",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-form": "^8.2.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "publish:npmWin": "SET NODE_ENV=production && rm -rf dist && mkdir dist && npx babel src/ --out-dir dist --copy-files",
    "publish:npmLnx": "SET NODE_ENV=production && rm -rf dist && mkdir dist && npx babel src/ --out-dir dist --copy-files",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9009 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "env",
      "stage-2"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.1.11",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.1.11",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.1.11",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.3",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8"
  }
}
```

Error message is:

> ./node_modules/acshb-react-common/src/components/button.js
>   SyntaxError: C:\workspace\react-sample\node_modules\acshb-react-common\src\components\button.js: Unexpected token (12:6)
>   if (props.loading) {
>     return (

Comment: Does [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57738073/how-to-export-react-component-as-npm-package-i-have-a-syntax-error) help you out?

Comment: CRA is not designed for component or components libraries.  It is specifically mentioned in the documentation at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#publishing-components-to-npm . This is why libraries such as nwb or bundlers like rollup (or very specific webpack configurations) are used for building, bundling, and deploying components and component libraries. CRA is specifically tailored for web apps and PWA.